# Paper Trail Gem: How to use a custom item_type for specific model

Tags: ruby, paper-trail-gem

Is there an option to configure the item_type for a version? I have a class Post, and the default item_type for that would be `Post`; is there an option to configure that be `Foo`?

UPDATE with example:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
end

post = Post.create # this creates a new post along with a version.
version = post.versions.first
version.item_type = 'Post' # Item type here is the name of the base model 'Post'.
```

Comment: I updated the title and post. It's for the paper trail gem.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an option to configure the item_type for a version? I have a class Post, and the default item_type for that would be Post; is there an option to configure that be Foo?

No. When you call `has_paper_trail`, it adds a polymorphic association named `item`. Therefore, **PaperTrail does not control the database column `item_type`**, ActiveRecord does.

Here is the definition of the `has_many` association:

```
has_many(
  versions_association_name, # Usually "versions"
  -> { order(model.timestamp_sort_order) }, # Usually "created_at"
  class_name: version_class_name, # Usually "PaperTrail::Version"
  as: :item # Specifies a polymorphic interface
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across this, realise its a bit old now but thought I'd share my solution as I had the same requirement. This is only a partial solution but it works me

I have extended the PaperTrail Version class and overriden the item_type getter

```
class AuditTrail < PaperTrail::Version
xss_foliate :except => [:object, :object_changes]

    def item_type
        if(self[:item_type] == "SomethingIWantToChange")
            return "Different String"
        end

        return self[:item_type]
    end
end
```

I then have set each of my models to use this class like so:

```
has_paper_trail :class_name => 'AuditTrail'
```

Then I can query the versions table and objects returned will run through the overridden getter and the item_type will be as I require:

```
audit_records = AuditTrail.where(someproperty: "something")
```

So this doesn't actually alter it in the DB when it is written, but is the best way I could find to present it differently to my frontend

Note that it doesn't alter the item_type if you fetch versions without using a query from your extended object i.e:

```
Someobject.find(1).versions.last
```

^ this still returns the item_type from the DB

Answer (score -1):

You want the `class_name` option.  This should work with your example:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail :class_name => 'Foo'
end
```

This will version the `Post` class as `Foo`.

You can find more details in the [Paper Trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) documentation in the [Custom Version Classes](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#6a-custom-version-classes) section.

Comment: The OP's question was about the database column `versions.item_type`. Passing `:class_name` to `has_paper_trail` should have no effect on this database column.